Is it possible to permanently / system wide disable non snake case warning emitted by rust compiler?
I am aware of #![allow(non_snake_case)] but this only disables the warning for that specific file/project.
How to disable this warning system wide?
I'm a beginner learning rust and warnings like this on every single recompilation is unhelpful and annoying. I mean variable names being non snake case is the least of my worries when I am struggling to do basic things, precious screen space being used up by useless warnings is just not right.

Maybe you can try compiling with RUSTFLAGS="-Anon_snake_case" variable (or environment variable)

^ That could also go in your ~/.cargo/config.toml under [build] rustflags = .... See cargo configuration.

Thanks a ton both of you, i didn't know cargo had a system wide configuration,  this was really starting to annoy me but thanks to you two i don't have to put up with this anymore. Thanks!!

If you are going this far, you may also want to simply specify nonstandard_style which is a lint group that covers non-snake-case, non-camel-case-types, and non-upper-case-globals lints.

I would say that if you're learning rust, you might as well get used to the conventions, otherwise you'll just have a bad habit to break as you progress. For instance, your code will be “poisonous”; if you post it to StackOverflow, you'll force everyone else to add #![allow(non_snake_case)] to their copy of your code in order to debug your problem for you without spurious warnings.

"i am a beginner learning rust" then why are you arguing rust is wrong? "variable names being non snake case is the least of my worries when i am struggling to do basic things" that's totally fair but you will only be a beginner for a very short time in your journey and having the discipline of that convention will help you for all the rest of it. Don't discount optimizing for the long haul. Also, if by "beginner learning rust" you mean beginner to programming, think carefully about your goals. Rust is honestly a pretty...ambitious...choice for your first language, maybe even for your second

@JaredSmith I think Rust is not a bad beginners language, it is pretty tough teacher but once you get it it saves on the time of debugging strange errors

@Zero could you edit and make your question more spot on and less about why. Then it will be a better fit here.

Don't work against the tools you use, work with them.

@Simson i had the felling someone would make a tyrranical edit like this. Mate let me ask you one thing, it's okay for all these people to lecture me about all this but as soon as i try to say a word you just edit it out? Well i hope at least you are feeling better from doing that cause pretty much this entire thread has left me with a bitter taste. GREAT JOB! Give yourself a pat on your back.

Correcting typos and removing rants are good things and appropriate, no need to rant, please. This is not a forum.

@thebusybee 100% agree but the real issue here is it seems to be oddly biased woudn't you agree. My edit got removed but somehow all these wise lectures which are off subject didn't get edited out including your own. But who am i kidding everyone is a hero in there own book, nothing i say will convince any of you of anything other than "I did exactly what was expected of me." I am strrongly debating if i should just start using vulgar language for no other reason than to get permantly banned, at least then i will never be able to have unpleasent interactions on this website again.

There is a difference between a question, answers, and comments. With the reputation I have I can edit questions and answers, but I cannot delete other's comments. -- This site strives to collect serious questions and accepted answers for future visitors to learn and find solutions for many years.

Wanting everything to remain strictly business is absolutely a fully agreeable goal, the trouble is "strictly business" moderation only happens loosely and sometimes which whether intended or not gives the appearance of highly biased moderation. Let it be known that i was "strictly business" up until the point everyone else started going off topic as opposed to directly answering the question. Which only made me think it's okay for me to chime in as well, but apparently not.

Personally speaking, I think you should not to it. This stated, to disable non-snake case warnings system-wide in Rust, you can use a more general approach that involves setting a default configuration for the Rust compiler (rustc) through environment variables or a global configuration file. Unfortunately, Rust does not support a simple configuration file like some other languages do, but you can work around this by setting up your environment or build scripts to consistently apply this setting across all your projects.
Here are a few methods to consider:
1. Using RUSTFLAGS Environment Variable
You can set the RUSTFLAGS environment variable in your shell to include the directive to allow non-snake case globally. This can be done by adding the following line to your shell configuration file (like .bashrc):
export RUSTFLAGS="-A non_snake_case"

This will append the flag to disable the non_snake_case lint every time Rust code is compiled in your shell session. Note that this will affect all Rust projects compiled in this environment.
Of course, not ideal when you have to change it in your CI or on each machine.
2. Cargo Configuration
If you prefer a Cargo-based solution that doesn't affect the global environment, you can configure Cargo to globally ignore certain lints by creating a .cargo/config.toml file in your home directory (or the appropriate configuration directory on your system) with the following content:
[build]
rustflags = ["-A non_snake_case"]

This will instruct Cargo to pass the -A non_snake_case argument to rustc every time a Cargo project is built on your system. This method is specific to Cargo and will not affect Rust code compiled without Cargo.

Note that you should prefer the config file approach, as it will work even when you will need per-project configuration, while RUSTFLAGS will be overridden and cause you weird warnings. Of course, if you've got to a stage at your learning where you learn about/needs to change something in RUSTFLAGS and you still hold your bad habits of non-standard style, then you have much bigger problems...
